# Firebase Phone Authentication Fails on Android with Missing Client Identifier Error Despite Enabled Google Play Integrity API

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm experiencing an issue with Firebase phone authentication on a real Android device. Despite having enabled the Google Play Integrity API, I'm encountering an error that prevents successful authentication. Here are the details:

```
[firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

Steps Taken:

- Confirmed that the "Android Device Verification" API is enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
- The google-services.json file is up-to-date and properly placed in the app's directory.
- The Firebase project is configured with the correct SHA-1 and SHA-256 certificate fingerprints.
- Phone authentication is enabled in the Firebase Authentication settings.
- Tested on a real device with the latest version of Google Play Services.